# How to decode unknown string format in java

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, string-decoding

I'm getting xml file which I need to handle in my SpringBoot Rest controller. But I have problem with parsing cyrillic chars. In my controller these symbols look like this: d�鲲㮮弯.

I was trying to decode using

```
 new String(xmlstring.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Windows-1251")
```

Also I was trying add to my controller:

```
 consumes = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

Top of my controller looks like this:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/endpoint", produces = "text/xml; charset=windows-1251", consumes = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
 @ApiOperation("...")
 public ResponseEntity<String> get(@RequestBody String xml)
```

I need to parse that to standart cyrillic shape.
Thank you.

Comment: why are you mixing 2 char sets?

Comment: I'm getting string in utf-8 format and trying to decode that to winsows-1251.

Comment: Strings by themselves (conceptually) don't have an encoding. The encoding determines how a string is represented when converted to and from bytes. Your first line of code is not correct: it encodes the string using UTF-8 and then decodes it as if it is Windows-1251. That's wrong, the bytes don't represent a Windows-1251-encoded string, because you've just encoded it as UTF-8...

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with this one**

```
String decoded = new String(xmlstring.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```